# how can i resolve this : The method received in the request-line is known by the origin server but not supported by the target resource

Tags: java

*I m receiving error as "HTTP Status 405 – Method Not Allowed" when trying to execute the below query, I am not sure what I can do to resolve this.*

> Also, someone could suggest me where can I get flight APIs for free for testing.

```
 package com.Gmaps.web.controller;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.Gmaps.web.DAO.GmapsDAOLayer;
import com.Gmaps.web.Model.GmapsModel;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class GmUserData
 */
public class GmUserData extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, String originAutocomplete) throws ServletException, IOException//, NumberFormatException
    {
//     String uid = request.getParameter("userid");
//     GmapsDAOLayer dao = new GmapsDAOLayer();
//     GmapsModel model = dao.getUser(uid);

       RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("UserPage.jsp");
       rd.forward(request, response);

      // float orgin = Float.parseFloat(request.getParameter("desti"));
       String orgin = request.getParameter("place"); 
       GmapsDAOLayer dao = new GmapsDAOLayer();
       GmapsModel model = dao.getUser(orgin);

       System.out.println("origin: "+orgin);
    }

    }
```

And here is my index.html

```
    <html>
<body>
<h2>Hello World!</h2>
<form action="getuserdata" method="get">
<input type= "text" name="userid"><br>
<input type= "text" name="firstname"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my web.xml

```
    <!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>GmUserData</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.Gmaps.web.controller.GmUserData</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>GmUserData</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/getuserdata</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

try with this `<form action="/getuserdata"` or just this `action="GmUserData"`

Comment: If I add  this: <form action="/getuserdata"> then I was getting 404 error

Comment: and this `action="GmUserData"`

Comment: action in form directs it to the page right? "GmUserData" is mine.java class. can we even mention .java class in it? I am not sure I'm in the beginner stage. So please guide me.

Comment: GmUserData is the servlet-name defined in the web.xml